# json_encode makes nothing in my php

Tags: php, json

I've this small code, I know I receive fine from the database because I made some print_r and work fine:

```
//build query SQL         
$query = $this ->select() 
    ->where('numBedrooms=?',$numBedrooms) 
    ->where('type=?',$type)
    ->where('state=?',$state)
    ->limit(8);//8 rows, with an offset of $recent_page*8-8
//execute query SQL
$rows=$this->fetchAll($query);
//encode json
$var= json_encode($rows);//-------->var is empty always!!
```

Comment: What does `fetchAll()` return?

Comment: an object, and inside has arrays and more objects

Comment: print_r gives me this result:
http://snipt.org/vsfh0#expand

Comment: `json_encode()` will only encode public properties in objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fetchAll() is returning an object like you say it is, then it would be wise to first convert this to an array and then to pass it to json_encode.  I do not believe json_encode work's with objects.

Comment: @Radiu: that doesn't mean it'll return what you might expect.

Comment: @Hamish, it will, as long as you expect to see the public properties.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert your row set to an array:

`$var= json_encode($rows->toArray());`

See Retrieving a Rowset as an Array on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html

Comment: This is the correct solution. Just to clarify: `json_encode` can serialize any PHP type (excluding resources). The OP's problem: `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset::_data` is protected and not directly accessible by `json_encode` or other functions. Hence the need to call `toArray()` to get at the protected data.

Comment: @powers1 Indeed. Thanks for contributing with additional details

Answer (score 3):

To add a different answer to this...

Zend provides different ways of accessing data. I find it easier to always work with arrays in Zend as it makes your code more portable.

Using Zend_Db_Table_Abstract:

```
class Model_MyStuff extends Zend_Db_Table_Absract
{
    protected $_name = 'Stuff';
    protected $_primary = 'StuffID';

    function getStuff()
    {
        $select = $this->select();

        $select->where('Active = 1');

        $results = $select->query()->fetchAll();
        if (count($results) > 0) return $results;
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code will return an array instead of objects which can immediately be passed into json_encode. The difference is you're asking the object to fetchAll($query) whereas I'm asing the select to query()->fetchAll(). I believe the select object needs to come from $this->select() for this to work however.